# StateTransformationLinearize - references?

Tags: nonlinear, implementation-details, control-systems, reference-request

I am impressed by [`StateTransformationLinearize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateTransformationLinearize.html), and I feel terribly bad for not having noticed this function before.

How does it work?

Does it attempt to find a $C^r$-conjugate of the system? If so, how does it do this?

Why can't it handle Affine State Space Models with symbolic parameters?

I would like to know more about this witchcraft.

For instance, slight changes in the coefficients of the featured examples, lead to failures in finding the transformation. Perhaps if I would figure out how this straightening is done, I could grasp something more about its applicability.

**Example**

```
    sys=AffineStateSpaceModel[{{4*Subscript[x, 1], 7*Subscript[x, 1]^2 + Subscript[x, 2]}, {{1}, {-1 + 2*Subscript[x, 1]}}, {Subscript[x, 2]}, {{0}}}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, 
 {{Subscript[\[FormalU], 1], 0}}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> None];
```

This is an example taken from the documentation. If you change the first coefficient, into a different number, i.e.:

```
sys=AffineStateSpaceModel[{{3*Subscript[x, 1], 7*Subscript[x, 1]^2 + Subscript[x, 2]}, {{1}, {-1 + 2*Subscript[x, 1]}}, {Subscript[x, 2]}, {{0}}}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}, 
     {{Subscript[\[FormalU], 1], 0}}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> None];
```

It already fails to find the transformation:

test = StateTransformationLinearize[
   sys, {{Subscript[z, 1], Subscript[z, 2]}, "InputState"}];

Outputting the following error msg:

*Control`StateAndFeedbackLinearizationsDump`StateSpaceLinarize::nclin: -- Message text not found -- (input-state)*

Comment: It would be helpful to have examples that work or fail, respectively, to find the transformation in question.

Comment: OK. I'll add an example right now.

Comment: Linearize is misspelled in the message -- odd since it is the message head.

Comment: You can inspect some methods via ``?*`*Linearize*``.  The misspelling comes from ``Control`StateAndFeedbackLinearizationsDump`ssLinearize0``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory behind this is in Chapter 5 of the book [Nonlinear Dynamical Control Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038797234X) by Henk Nijmeijer and Arjan van der Schaft.

The more powerful linearization is [FeedbackLinearize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackLinearize.html) which uses feedback, in addition to state transformation, to linearize a system.

Comment: Thank you very much Suba! I was actually interested only in straightening because I was willing to see the "linear" properties of a nonlinear control applied to a linear system.